# Is it possible to use a certain data value of a topic for executing some code?

Tags: ros, rosnode, rosrun, rostopic, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i will try to be as clear as possible.
I have a ROS topic in which are published only 0 and 1. In another node i have a subscriber that is subscribed to that topic. Then i had an idea to implement a callback function, that as some code to execute inside, that is called by the subscriber.
Let's say that every ten data valued 1 a data valued 0 will show up in the topic.
So my question is, is it possible to execute the code inside the callback function only when the subscriber reads 0 in the topic?
I mean with a sort of if(...) {...} mechanism or something similar.
I apologize if it's not clear, i can provide other details or explanations; just let me know.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: here is the correct code of the callback function that i mentioned in the comment:

```
void orderCallback(const std_msgs::Bool::ConstPtr& msg)
{

if (msg->data == 0)
{
chdir("/home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor");

system("get_hrv -R my_data_file.txt >doc.txt");
}
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249120/is-it-possible-to-use-a-certain-data-value-of-a-topic-for-executing-some-code?/) by [Marcofon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28427/marcofon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. A callback is just a function. Inside this you can do whatever you want. Just check the data and use an if clause.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcofon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28427/marcofon/) on 2016-11-30**:
Thank you for your reply! Since i don't know how to check the topic values, can you please try to explain it to me? Below there is the code:

```
void orderCallback()
{
chdir("/home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor");

system("get_hrv -R my_data_file.txt >doc.txt");
}
```

**Comment by [Marcofon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28427/marcofon/) on 2016-11-30**:
@mig This is the subscriber:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("semaphore", 1000, orderCallback);
```

And, as i said in the question, i have only boolean values.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-30**:
check out the tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B), your callback is also not correct.

**Comment by [Marcofon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28427/marcofon/) on 2016-11-30**:
@mig I have already checked it before posting. Can you help me with the code? If you can, of course. Thank you again.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-12-01**:
What kind of message do you have? this needs to go in the callback function definition. See l.34 of the listener.cpp in the tutorial. Then, depending on the fields of the message, you can access this as shown in l.36 `msg->data`. But note, that the `String.msg` has a field called `data`. You need to

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-12-01**:
adapt this accordingly for whatever your message you use. Then, implement your logic in whatever way you like...

**Comment by [Marcofon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28427/marcofon/) on 2016-12-01**:
Thank you for your reply! I tried something like this:

```
void orderCallback(const std_msgs::Bool::ConstPtr& msg)
{
bool data;
msg->data;
if (data = 0)
{
chdir("/home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor");
system("get_hrv -R my_data_file.txt >doc.txt");
}
}
```

**Comment by [Marcofon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28427/marcofon/) on 2016-12-01**:
...i tried to adapt the callback of the tutorial to my case. Anyway, it doesn't seem to work. What i'm missing? P.S. is `data == 0` in my real code, it was only a typo in the comment. Thank you again @mig

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-12-01**:
try `if (msg->data == 0)`.

You are just creating an uninitalized bool `data` but don't assign `msg->data` to it.

**Comment by [Marcofon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28427/marcofon/) on 2016-12-01**:
Yes, i was writing to you right now! I made the exact change that you suggested to me before seeing your new comment! Thank you very much indeed! I'll post the solution as an edit to my question. Thank you again @mig !!